# PBR dielectric material in luxrender?

Tags: materials, node-editor, luxrender-render-engine

I have found many tutorials on PBR dielectric materials in cycles, but how do I do this in luxrender? In the past I would use a glossy material, but it handles roughness diffrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the [Glossy material type](http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxRender_Materials_Glossy) in luxrender does what you want out of the box.

Unlike the glossy shader in cycles, the luxrender glossy material includes a "matte" component (diffuse in cycles-speak), making it *loosely* analogous to the following cycles setup:

[image]

Luxrender glossy node for reference:

[image]

---

#### Render comparison

Cycles
[image]

Luxrender
[image]

<sub>I'm not really sure why the cycles render is dimmer than the luxrender example in this case. The difference appears to be in the diffuse part of things. If someone knows what's going on here, I'd definitely like to hear about it</sub>

Comment: It looks like the difference between the two renders is actually due to the way the lamps are being interpreted

Comment: How do I convert the roughness from cycles to luxrender?

Comment: @SupaKoopaTroopa64 In the luxrender glossy material, I believe the "Roughness" setting (separated into U-roughness and V-roughness in the properties panel) is equivalent to the roughness setting on the cycles glossy shader, and the "Sigma" setting is equivalent to the roughness setting on the cycles diffuse shader.

Comment: Oh, so these settingsmust be changed together.

Comment: Well, diffuse roughness isn't linked to glossy roughness, no. I mentioned both, as I couldn't be sure which one you were referring to.

Comment: In this tutorial it says they should be conected. At 38:50 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4

Comment: @SupaKoopaTroopa64 It appears you are right; at least, [other PBR systems](http://www.marmoset.co/toolbag/learn/pbr-theory) keep diffuse and glossy roughness together. However, you might want them separate anyway, in case you want finer control. [Disney's PBR shader does this](https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf) (see page 13). Perhaps if you have a varnished matte surface, you might want to set the diffuse roughness high, yet keep the glossy roughness down, as the varnish forms a perfectly smooth (but transparent) surface on top of the matte.

Comment: Of course, you could also handle the above scenario by mixing (i.e. layering) between multiple shaders. As a matter of fact, the Disney PBR shader appears to have just such an extra glossy layer built in (labeled "clearCoat"). In the end, how you set up your nodegroup is up to your own preferences. Do you want to take a "Disney approach", favoring speed, workflow, and artistic flexibility in order to pack as many common setups as possible into one big shader? Or take a more modular approach and make smaller nodes which work in multiple-node, layered setups?

Answer (score 2):

What way is it not physically accurate? It is, and mostly follows the same conventions as realtime "diffuse/specular" PBR shaders. Just remember it uses "roughness" (shiny=0) while it somehow became a convention to use "glossiness" (shiny=1) with diffuse/specular. So just remember you need to diffuse, specular, roughness, and normal channels in a tool like Substance. Otherwise, you just plug in textures and go.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm not trying to begin an argument, and sorry if I don't know how to post properly (I am a beginner at this). I attach six QUICK tests, and the source .blend file. They show how Luxrender image suffers from a "velvet" appearance on the very upper part of the ball, and the horizontal plane emitts light. Yafaray image is not very accurate since its glossy matterial cannot set ior properly (known behavior). See how Luxrender white carpaint is OK, but not editable. I would like somebody to show me a way to design a proper glossy material in Luxrender :(
(I can send the blend file if somebody's interested)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the future please [edit] your answer, instead of adding new ones with more information.

Comment: Whoops, just saw this now. If you like, you can upload your blend here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/630/599. I'm curious, did you control for tonemapping used by different engines or anything?

Answer (score -2):

I've been trying to create a phisically correct glossy material in luxrender for Blender for more than two weeks. Seriously, I'm nowhere near a beginner in photo-realistic rendering (I been working in this since good old POV-Ray 3.0 years :). I've tried every known way to achieve this task: glossy material, a matte base plus a glossy_coating, layered, car_paint, etc. To my astonishment, all of them lack the same excess of shine (in fact, there's a way: chosing one of the predefined car-paint shaders, which have no way to be edited -even color; if you swich to manual settings, the material fails). This is the real reason for the difference between Cycles (correct) and Luxrender (too bright). So, to my knowledge THERE IS ACTUALLY NO WAY TO ACHIVE A PHISICALLY CORRECT GLOSSY MATERIAL IN LUXRENDER. I know this is hard to believe, but sadly, after my thoroughly tests and comparisons with other engines (Indigo, Cycles, Mitsuba, and Yafaray). This is is my conclusion:
"Lux glossy material is buggy: at shallow angles (object contours) it is not energy conserving (it reflects more light than it receives)"

Comment: Ok so you take a very low quality "answer" and turn it in to a wall of text rant. That's not going to help you. Your now deleted answer, was deleted because it did not even start to answer the question, it was not helpful enough to be converted to a comment and so a mod deleted it. How does "Lux glossy material is buggy: at shallow angles it is not energy conserving" help the OP make a PBR dielectric material in Luxrender?

Comment: Could you expand on your tests/comparisons with other engines, and/or how you know lux isn't conserving energy properly? I'd be interested learning the reason for this behavior too.