# Luxrender PBR materials

Tags: materials, pbr, luxrender-render-engine

*I know that you should usually ask questions about "direct problems" here but there is a problem where I can't find an answer to. There is a quite similar question but the answers don't really help me at all:
[PBR dielectric material in luxrender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60551/pbr-dielectric-material-in-luxrender)*

**Now here is the question:**

A few days ago I have seen an amazing tutorial about PBR materials by BlenderGuru:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3wghbZ-Vh4

However, this tutorial only features the Cycles Render engine. Since I am trying to get used to LuxRender I cannot just use the .blend file from the project. I have already thought about just recreating the steps from the tutorials but since I am new to Blender I think it is better to ask for an advice.

Has anyone experience with LuxRender and PBR materials and give me a hint what to look up?

Thanks for any help.

Kind regards,

Fabian Lins

Comment: Have you researched which render engine is better for your needs before committing to learn another one? For faster learning I would just follow Andrew's, the BlenderGuru, tutorial to get familiar with Blender.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For my current projects Cycles is probably the way to go however, I have heard that LuxRender is more accurate when it comes to realism and I don't think it is a bad idea to start getting used to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Disney Shader in LuxCore Render Engine with PBR textures.

Connect Albedo multiplied by Ambient Occlusion (if any) in Disney Material Base Color. Normal map in Bump socket (Checking Normal map tick box). Roughness and Metallic in their corresponding sockets. See Displacement note below.

Things to check:

- Base Color is the Albedo multiply by Ambient Occlusion and both needs gamma 2.20 (sRGB Color Conversion for a standard PBR texture.)
  All other maps (metallic,roughness,displacement needs gamma 1.0 (Linear color for a standard PBR texture)
- for Normal map check normal map in image node
- for Displacement use height Displacement node>plug the displace texture in height socket and a subdivision node(For limiting subdivision amount) in shape socket and connect Height Displacement node in shape socket of Material output.

For more clarity, here is a PBR setup tutorial for Lux: https://youtu.be/AXACxDlvZAY

See the image attach:

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks for taking the time and expanding the answer.